# Extension Functions -> Delegation

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to programming & currently on a course to learn how to program in Kotlin. I have a problem on the course I currently learn from.

Its really hard for me to solve this kind of problem. I found it very hard to conceptualize what the problem is. I didn't know where to start, i didn't know what to search. Reading the extension functions theory over & over again didn't really help me to understand what the problem really is.

so here is the problem below:

Assume there is `fun next(prev: Int): Int`. Implement `fun Int.nextValue(): Int` which returns the same value as the first function.

thanks in advance

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extension methods** allow you to add methods to an object without changing the object class definition. This is often useful when you get a library from a third party and don't have access to the source code.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(next(6));   // run function
    println(6.nextValue());  // run method from Int object
}

fun next(prev: Int): Int = prev + 1;

fun Int.nextValue(): Int = this + 1;  // add method to Int class
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions in Kotlin are based on the theory of extensions in programming language theory. Some languages, like Swift, allow you to extend a class that you don't own. This idea of extensionality comes from the need to add custom members to a previously existing type. This allows for creating Domain Specific Languages, in order to make programming in certain domains easier to read and write and maintain. It's becoming an increasingly popular concept in language development, which then leads to the idea of typeclasses. But let's start with the basics.

An extension method allows us to call a procedure with a receiver. A receiver is a type that is almost like the subject of the procedure. Think about speech for example: We have a subject and an object. Our subject is what we use as the receiver of our message, such as "I want to go to the store". We are saying that the subject *I* in conjunction with the clause *want to go to* and the object *the store*, allows us to construct a message *around* the subject. We know the message is *about* the subject, *I*. You can think of the receiver of an extension method to be the subject of the method.

```kotlin
fun Int.next(): Int = this + 1
```

This above method is exactly equivalent to the following function

```kotlin
fun next(prev: Int): Int = prev + 1
```

This reason why they are equivalent is because we are taking the *prev* parameter and turning that into a *receiver* or *subject* because we want this method to be revolved around our parameter. We are *extending* the functionality of the *Int* type, such that we can use our newly acquired method as if the method is a part of *Int*, even though it isn't. The way this will be seen by the Java Virtual Machine will be *something* like this:

```java
public static int next(int receiver){
    return receiver + 1;
}
```

As you can see, we are also using the *this* operator, which is provided by the fact that we are acting as if we are *inside the receiver type*. Using *this* inside the body of an extension method is the same as using *this* inside a newly declared class.

```kotlin
class A(val name: String){
    fun a(){
        println(this.name)
    }
}
```

Now, *next* is a really basic example of extensions, but they can be really capable of some rather complex things. A better example of an extension method would be to split a string by line breaks and filter out blank lines.

```kotlin
fun String.linesNoBlank() =
    this.lines()
        .filter{ it.isNotBlank() }
```

This method could be not only used but also expanded to do other kinds of computations. Imagine doing this on a database to filter out certain kinds of data, such as a query.